# Why am I getting a function error when using replace() to replace strings in a table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql called '`raw_data_file`' and it has a 7 columns and the last one is called '`status`' and consists of strings only.

I am trying to replace all instances of '`PASS1_SUCCEEDED`' with '`S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDE`D'.

Here is my code:

```
select status from raw_data_file;

UPDATE raw_data_file 
  SET status = replace (status, 'PASS1_SUCCEEDED`', 'S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED');
```

For some reason, I am getting the error:

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function replace(raw_data_file_status_e, unknown, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 35
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function replace(raw_data_file_status_e, unknown, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 35
```

Any ideas what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: What data type exactly is the `status` column? It seems that `status` is an enum, not a `text` (or `varchar`) column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error hints, try explicit casts:

```
UPDATE raw_data_file SET status = replace (status, 'PASS1_SUCCEEDED'::text, 'S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED'::text);
```

Btw, if your `status` field always contains only ONE of these text (so it cant contains things like `PASS1_SUCCEEDED;PASS2_SUCCEEDED`, you dont need string replace, you can simply do

```
UPDATE raw_data_file SET status = 'S3UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED' WHERE status = 'PASS1_SUCCEEDED';
```

Comment: Awsome thanks- your second point has saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: For me, explicit types helped with this error because it lead to a new error where I hadn't noticed my deeply nested functions were missing a comma. (Specifically, a comma after the closing parens of an inner `replace` function and before the outer `replace` function's other arguments).